# Cannot find reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, serialization

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
```

VS says, **The type or namespace name 'Formatters' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization'**. Well, I should add this reference. Click Project > Add reference > .NET, there I can see only System.Runtime.Serialization, nothing like Formatters.

System.Runtime.Serialization.dll appears to be under `c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\` - there are no Formatters, neither Formatters.Binary there.

How to find this reference?

Comment: unfortunately, there is no `BinaryFormatter` in wp7 sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently Silverlight does not have the `BinaryFormatter`. However an open source project exists that may be able to provide similar functionality for you. It is called [sharpSerializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html). **It will work with Silverlight and WP7**.

I am keeping the other half my answer below, while not appropriate for Silverlight, may be helpful for those that are still missing said reference in other projects, as it should correct it.

---

For other projects that do not use Silverlight, and have access to the `BinaryFormatter` you may have your target framework set incorrectly.

Make sure you are using the full `.NET Framework 4 Profile` and not the `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` in your project as your target framework. See the image below, you can find these settings in your project's properties.

[image: Setting the Target framework]

Comment: Was just writing a comment about this too, this cause would be my guess.

Comment: Apparently the `BinaryFormatter` is not supported in Silverlight, which I was unaware of. I have updated my answer to provided a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

The `BinaryFormatter` is not supported in `Silverlight` (or Windows Phone).